# Errors installing python33 on CentOS 6.7

Tags: python, linux

I get the following error message whenever I try to install python33 in CentOS 6.7.

```
sudo yum install python33
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * extras: mirrors.chkhosting.com
 * updates: centos-mirror.jchost.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python33.x86_64 0:1.1-13.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-jinja2 for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-nose for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-simplejson for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-setuptools for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-sphinx for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-sqlalchemy for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-virtualenv for package: python33-1.1-13.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python33-python.x86_64 0:3.3.2-12.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.2-12.el7.centos for package: python33-python-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python33-runtime for package: python33-python-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython3.3m.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python33-python-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package python33-python-jinja2.noarch 0:2.6-12.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-markupsafe for package: python33-python-jinja2-2.6-12.el7.centos.noarch
---> Package python33-python-nose.noarch 0:1.3.0-3.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-3.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.2.0-2.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-sphinx.noarch 0:1.1.3-8.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-docutils for package: python33-python-sphinx-1.1.3-8.el7.centos.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-pygments for package: python33-python-sphinx-1.1.3-8.el7.centos.noarch
---> Package python33-python-sqlalchemy.noarch 0:0.7.9-5.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-virtualenv.noarch 0:1.10.1-2.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python33-python-devel for package: python33-python-virtualenv-1.10.1-2.el7.centos.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python33-python-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.2-12.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-docutils.noarch 0:0.11-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.2-12.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.6()(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdbm_compat.so.4()(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdbm.so.4()(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5()(64bit) for package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package python33-python-markupsafe.noarch 0:0.11-10.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-python-pygments.noarch 0:1.5-3.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package python33-runtime.x86_64 0:1.1-13.el7.centos will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: libffi.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: libgdbm_compat.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: libgdbm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am used to ubuntu where apt-get seems to work really well.  I thought yum was supposed to be kind of similar.  Shouldn't it just find and download the dependencies as well?

Comment: Both`apt` and `yum` will fail like this if there is a problem with the upstream repository, which looks like it might be the case.

Comment: I kind of just worked around the issue by converting my project to python 2

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have a fresh CentOS 6.7 system (with a recent `yum upgrade`):

```
[root@b854039a02fe /]# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

There is no `python33` package in the default set of repositories:

```
[root@b854039a02fe /]# yum install python33
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: ftp.usf.edu
No package python33 available.
```

There is apparently [an SCL repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL#head-9c6aea9c13b921d5258446c4c5e5886571bdb741) with `python33`, so:

```
[root@b854039a02fe /]# yum install centos-release-SCL
```

And then:

```
[root@b854039a02fe /]# yum install python33
[...]

Installed:
  python33.x86_64 0:1.1-12.el6.centos.alt                                       

Dependency Installed:
  python33-python.x86_64 0:3.3.2-14.el6.centos.alt                              
  python33-python-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.2-14.el6.centos.alt                        
  python33-python-docutils.noarch 0:0.11-1.el6.centos.alt                       
  python33-python-jinja2.noarch 0:2.6-11.el6.centos.alt                         
  python33-python-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.2-14.el6.centos.alt                         
  python33-python-markupsafe.noarch 0:0.11-10.el6.centos.alt                    
  python33-python-nose.noarch 0:1.3.0-1.el6.centos.alt                          
  python33-python-pygments.noarch 0:1.5-3.el6.centos.alt                        
  python33-python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-1.el6.centos.alt                    
  python33-python-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.2.0-1.el6.centos.alt                    
  python33-python-sphinx.noarch 0:1.1.3-8.el6.centos.alt                        
  python33-python-sqlalchemy.noarch 0:0.7.9-4.el6.centos.alt                    
  python33-python-virtualenv.noarch 0:1.10.1-1.el6.centos.alt                   
  python33-runtime.x86_64 0:1.1-12.el6.centos.alt                               
  scl-utils.x86_64 0:20120927-27.el6_6                                          

Complete!
```

Maybe the particular repository mirror you were pointing at was incomplete.  Consider running:

```
yum clean all
```

And then retrying.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP.  This did not solve it.  But thank you for the suggestion.